# activate main application window when clicking embedding console

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-console

There is a embedded console in my program. When the main window is not active and clicking in the console won't bring the main window to front. In spy++ there isn't any message sent to the main window when clicking on the console.

Here's a sample to illustrate the problem:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nShowCmd)
{
    static TCHAR lpszAppName[] = TEXT("HelloWin");
    HWND      hwnd;
    MSG       msg;
    WNDCLASS  wc;

    wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = lpszAppName;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"),
            lpszAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(lpszAppName,
        TEXT("The Hello Program"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            AllocConsole();
            freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout); // redirect std::cout to console
            std::cout << "test console" << std::endl;

            // get console handle
            HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
            SetParent(console, hwnd);
            ShowWindow(console, SW_MAXIMIZE);
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Is it possible to activate the main application by clicking in the console?

Comment: call `SetWindowLong(console, GWL_STYLE, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE);` before `ShowWindow` - but there must more reliable way of doing this, for example by using edit control to make your own output console.

Comment: That's it, set it as child window solves the problem.